# Access from anywhere in the world?

Tags: ssh, connection, vnc, ipad

How can I acess to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with SSH and VNC from anywhere in the world with a wifi connection? I found [this application](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/issh-ssh-vnc-console/id287765826?mt=8), but can this app access my Ubuntu system from anywhere in the world?

Comment: Can you read [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87443/how-to-access-a-machine-through-vnc-using-ssh?rq=1) and see if the answers help? If they do, you should delete this question since it would be a duplicate.

Comment: @TomBrossman That question is about how to run a VNC server. This question is about how to make one available over the Internet to anyone (and an answer to this should further take into account the possibility of the user's WAN IP changing). These are very different questions. Furthermore, when a question *is* a duplicate, it can simply be *closed as a duplicate*--it is not necessary to delete the question or to ask the OP to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use this application to access your Ubuntu.
But there are two thing to take note of:

1. SSH or VNC service should be installed in Ubuntu and configured properly to provide service.
2. If your computer does not have a static IP address, a dynamic DNS service will also be needed.