# How to set up remote desktop sharing through SSH?

Tags: ssh, vnc, openssh, vncviewer

Is there a way to view (and control) a remote desktop through SSH? I will not have physical access to the remote host machine.

Comment: vino non SSH specific: https://askubuntu.com/questions/4474/enable-remote-vnc-from-the-commandline

Answer (score 66, accepted):

### Method 1 :

This can be achieved with vino vnc server & remmina (both come default with ubuntu; if not install it by running `sudo apt-get install remmina`). Then Run Following commands from local computer in terminal prompt:

1. `ssh -Y gman@remote`. Use trusted X11 forwarding, otherwise it wont work
2. `vino-preferences`. It will open vino-preferences.

   [image: vino-preference]
3. Also Click `configure network automatically to accept connection`. **But don't enter any password, its base64 encoded**. Then click close. Then run:

   ```
   sudo -s

   export DISPLAY=:0.0

   xhost +

   /usr/lib/vino/vino-server &
   ```

   It will start the vino server.
4. Logout from server:

   ```
   xhost -

   Press CTRL+C twice

   exit

   exit
   ```
5. Then open **remmina**. Choose `vnc` under protocol.

   Under `basic` tab put server address in `server` field.

   On ssh tab click `enable ssh tunnel`. Under `ssh authentication`, it could be `password` or `public key`:

   [image: remmina-preference]

   Click save. And then double click connection-name(home-desktop as shown in the picture) to start browsing remote desktop.

---

### Method 2:

`x11vnc` is a simple VNC server and you won't have to mess around with Gnome settings or 500 firewalls, just install `x11vnc` on all your computers (with puppet or whatever you're using for mass-control).

Then from your local computer run:

```
ssh user@host -L 5900:localhost:5900 "x11vnc -display :0 -noxdamage"
```

Obviously swapping `user@host` for the username and hostname/IP of the remote computer.

And then use a VNC client of your choice to connect to `localhost:5900`. The SSH command starts a vnc server on the remote computer and then tunnels back that port over SSH. You don't have to open up any ports (as long as you can already SSH).

If your computers have funny display settings, you might do better to leave off the `-display :0` segment in the SSH command. `x11vnc` will then automatically try to find the right display.

---

Source: [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87443/how-to-access-a-machine-through-vnc-using-ssh)

Comment: If you are using vncviewer with a slow ssh connection, your command should look like `vncviewer localhost::5900 -viewonly -encodings "tight" -quality 0` (on Debian/Ubuntu the viewer is from tightvnc) or `vncviewer localhost::5900 -viewonly -PreferredEncoding tight QualityLevel=0` (on Red Hat/Fedora the viewer is from tigervnc), where quality level on both Debian and Redhat is between 0 and 9, where 9 is best, but needs fast connection.

Comment: @erik Thanks for explaining how to use it with `vncviewer` for slow connection. I personally, will probably set `QualityLevel=4 or 5` because `0 qualitylevel` (which is `256 colors`, I think) is too dull for me.

Comment: Your "Method 2" is perfect for a quick access to the physical display remotely without any special permanent settings. I needed to add the -auth parameter as explained in the error message when I executed the command but otherwise works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @gerky method 3 would be NoMachine, is currently the fastest and free (despite not opensource), and work on android too

Comment: For method 2, I had to use `-auth guess` and run it as root. Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: In my case I receive the error: `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"` after executing `xhost +`. Any idea on how to correct this?

Comment: You might need to `sudo apt install remmina remmina-plugin-vnc` if your distro doesn't ship remmina with vnc support included by default

Comment: Where is vino-preferences coming from?

Comment: According to the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vino), `vino-preferences` was removed, and Vino is configured using `gnome-control-center`. Unfortunately, gnome-control-center does not work for me over SSH.

Answer (score 11):

### Overview of Solution

Assuming you have already setup an `OpenSSH Server` on your host machine, you must first enable desktop control on your host machine. If you can first enable desktop control on your host machine locally, head to 1a. If you must first enable desktop control on your host machine remotely, head to 1b.

Next create a Remote Desktop Client profile on your client machine in order to connect to the host machine through an SSH tunnel and ultimately view and control the host machine's desktop through an SSH tunnel.

### 1a. Locally Enable Remote Control of Host Machine

Do the following on the host machine:

```
vino-preferences
```

- `vino-preferences` also in Dash under `Desktop Sharing`

[image]

1. Tick `Allow other users to view your desktop`
2. Tick `Allow other users to control your desktop`
3. Tick `Require the user to enter this password`
4. Enter a difficult to guess passphrase
5. Close

### 1b. Remotely Enable Remote Control of Host Machine

Do the following on the client machine, replacing `123.123.12.3` with your host machine's IP address:

```
ssh -Y 123.123.12.3
```

- -Y,      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.

```
vino-preferences
```

- `vino-preferences` also in Dash under `Desktop Sharing`

[image]

1. Tick `Allow other users to view your desktop`
2. Tick `Allow other users to control your desktop`
3. Tick `Require the user to enter this password`
4. Enter a difficult to guess passphrase
5. Close

### Create Remote Desktop Client profile on your Client Machine

Do the following on the client machine:

```
remmina
```

- remmina also in Dash under `Remmina Remote Desktop Client`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or Connection > New

[image]

1. Fill in your IP address [123.123.12.3] where it says `Server`
2. Switch to the `SSH` tab

[image]

3. Tick `Enable SSH Tunnel`
4. Point your Desktop Client to your non-standard SSH port
5. Set your `SSH Authentication` `<username>` and mode
6. Connect

### View and Control Host Machine

On the client machine, when asked for `<username>`'s password, enter it to create the SSH tunnel. When asked for the VNC password, enter the passphrase you previously entered into the host machine.

If successful at this step, you should now be viewing and controlling the host machine's desktop from your client machine through an SSH tunnel.

Comment: This seems quite comprehensive, but where is the custom port 12345 defined on the host?

Comment: I'm guessing you need an ssh command run from the client somewhere, something like: 
ssh -L 12345:localhost:5900 user@server_ip
before using the remote client as described.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to set a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install from a remote ssh connection with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
read -e -p "VNC Password: " -i "ubuntu" password
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/enabled true
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/prompt-enabled false
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/authentication-methods "['vnc']"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/require-encryption false
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/vnc-password \"\'$(echo -n $password | base64)\'\"
dconf dump /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/
sudo service lightdm restart
```

The quoting is important for any of the string settings (single ticks inside quotes).  For dconf to be able to write it needs access to XWindows, so that's why the export DISPLAY part is needed.  I think you still need to be logged in to the desktop on the actual Ubuntu machine to connect with VNC after this.
The dump command is just there to confirm all the settings took hold, you don't really need that.

Optionally you may want to do this if you want to keep the display up all the time:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-enabled false
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/session/idle-delay "uint32 0"
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You could use ssh to start a vnc session
2. Use `Xnest` with X11 forwording to remotely start a session and forward it to your current computer. (I do this from time to time with my pi) <sub>[man page](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/Xnest.1.html)</sub>

I use `Xnest` like so:

- `Xnest :1 -ac &`
- then `DISPLAY=:1 . /etc/X11/Xsession`

Comment: Unfortunately, xnest is also too slow to work over SSH a decade later.

Answer (score 1):

**How to start Vino server remotely without forwarding X (command line-only)**

Log on the remote computer as the user who will share their desktop and forward port 5900 to the same port on localhost. With PuTTY, the redirection is set in Connection/SSH/Tunnels. With a command line, use:

```
 ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 user@remote-computer
```

Install `vino-server` if it is not already installed. For example:

```
sudo apt install vino
```

Enable desktop sharing (matching the display number on 1st and 2nd lines):

```
echo $DISPLAY
export DISPLAY=:0
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set org.gnome.Vino enabled true
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled false
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server
```

Start a VNC viewer and connect to `localhost` for the VNC server address.

Comment: Got the following . Seems like this all assumes you are already logged in to a GUI console? 

```No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot open display: 
Run 'vino-server --help' to see a full list of available command line options
```

Answer (score 1):

**In the server PC.**

- Open 'vino-preferences' from the terminal or 'Desktop Sharing' using dash.

[image: vino-preferences]

**In the client PC (from where you want to control the server UI).**

- Keep the settings as shown in the images below (with changes at the place of username and IP).

[image: *Basic* tab]
[image: *Advanced* tab]
[image: *SSH* tab]

**Pitfalls.**

- When I tried to set the vino-preferences in the server from a remote PC using SSH, it got changed, but the connection did not happen. I had to do it in the server machine directly (not remotely). I don't' know the reason for this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

based on @Khurshid Alam answer I present the following snippet:

`ssh $TARGETHOST -L 5900:localhost:5900 "x11vnc -localhost -display :0 -noxdamage" &; sleep 10 && vinagre localhost`

- **It is one command that does not require any interaction**
- It creates the SSH tunnel with port forwarding, starts `x11vnc` in a reasonably safe way and launches and connects the VNC viewer
- It requires x11vnc on the target host, but no further configuration
- It requires vinagre on your PC, but you can trivially change it for another VNC viewer

Comment: mnagel's method is working for me, but I have to open a second terminal to open vinagre (sorry can't add comment because of silly reputation-rule)

Comment: It seems to require X to be running on remote. This is not something to take for granted.

Comment: `(sleep 10 && vinagre localhost) & ssh 192.168.1.106 -L 5900:localhost:5900 "vncserver :0; cat"` is what I ended up with, when it doesn't