# Problem connecting to remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote, remmina, vino

I am having a problem connecting to my desktop remotely over ssh tunnel.

Host and Guest machines are Ubuntu 14.04.  SSH is working, high numbered alternate port. X forwarding works.

I followed the directions [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304017/how-to-set-up-remote-desktop-sharing-through-ssh/304720#304720) to set up vino server and use remmina.  When starting the remmina connection, it simply hangs.  Eventually I have to cancel.  On the remote host, the entries for the connection in `/var/log/auth.log` are:

```
Nov 18 08:54:49 Bear systemd-logind[31920]: New session 13 of user patton.
Nov 18 08:54:50 Bear sshd[12394]: error: connect_to bear.ddns.net port 5900: failed.
Nov 18 08:55:54 Bear sshd[12394]: channel_by_id: 0: bad id: channel free
Nov 18 08:55:54 Bear sshd[12394]: Disconnecting: Received ieof for nonexistent channel 0.
Nov 18 08:55:54 Bear sshd[12356]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user patton
```

Any suggestions for troubleshooting, how can I get this to work?

EDIT: Following Letizia's question, closed and restarted vino-server on remote host: Here is the output:

```
(vino-server:19903): EggSMClient-CRITICAL **: egg_sm_client_set_mode: assertion 'global_client == NULL || global_client_mode == EGG_SM_CLIENT_MODE_DISABLED' failed
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Autoprobing TCP port in (all) network interface
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Autoprobing selected port 5900
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Re-binding socket to listen for VNC connections on TCP port 5900 in (all) interface
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Clearing securityTypes
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Clearing securityTypes
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Advertising authentication type: 'No Authentication' (1)
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Re-binding socket to listen for VNC connections on TCP port 5900 in (all) interface
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Clearing securityTypes
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Clearing authTypes
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
19/11/2014 12:53:26 AM Advertising authentication type: 'VNC Authentication' (2)
```

Comment: It seems that there is a connection problem with port 5900. Did you check if vino server is running and listening on port 5900? Also if your server is behind a router, did you forward port 5900 on the router to the local IP address of the computer you are trying to access?

Comment: @Letizia, I'm not sure I know how to check what port vino-server is listening on.  When starting vino-server there were messages referencing both port 5900 and 5901. But I didn't log them. Since I'm tunnelling through ssh, why would the port need to be open on the router?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

It the linked post did not mention it and it didn't occur to me that to check the "Tunnel via Loopback Address" box on the SSH tab in Remmina. That ended up working.  Tragically slow, but it worked.  Thansk for the thoughts.